# Intel SIMD - How can I check if an __m256* contains any non-zero values

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx

I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler. I am trying to find out if a 256 bit vector contains any non-zero values. I have tried `res_simd = ! _mm256_testz_ps(*pSrc1, *pSrc1);` but it does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_mm256_testz_ps` just tests the sign bits - in order to test the *values* you'll need to compare against 0 and then extract the resulting mask, e.g.

```
__m256 vcmp = _mm256_cmp_ps(*pSrc1, _mm256_set1_ps(0.0f), _CMP_EQ_OQ);
int mask = _mm256_movemask_ps(vcmp);
bool any_nz = mask != 0xff;
```