# Decrement bytes in XMM/YMM and compare to zero

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, avx

I have a bunch of unsigned single-byte counters and I'd like to simultaneously decrement them all and if any of them reaches 0, set the carry bit. And if the carry bit is set, I want to reset the counter(s) that reached 0 back to their original number. Is such a thing possible with AVX?

e.g.

- byte 4 of xmm3 starts at 200, when it reaches 0, it is reset back to 200.
- byte 5 of xmm3 starts at 150, when it reaches 0, it is reset back to 150.

I am also open to incrementing numbers up to a maximum for each byte and then resetting each to 0 when they reach the maximum.

The main thing is to keep these counters cycling, and when any of them reaches the limit I need a flag bit set.

Comment: Sure, most ISAs including AVX2 have byte compares for exact equality against a vector of max values or against zero, and can blend according to a compare mask.  It's not great for critical-path latency, though.  You're looking for `vpcmpeqb` and `vpblendvb`.  (And `vpmovmskb eax, cmp_result` / `add eax, 0xffffffff` to set CF if any bits were set in the compare mask.)  Or more efficiently, `vpcmpeqb` / `vpandn` to zero out bytes that matched the limit, leaving others unmodified, for up-counters instead of down-counters.  (All this after a `vpaddb` or `vpsubb` of an all-ones vector, of course.)

Comment: So you want your counters to reset when the reach zero, not when the would have *passed* zero?  So not under the conditions where `sub eax, 1` would set the carry flag.  (That's fine, but rules out the optimization of skipping the compare and using the MSB as the control for `vpblendvb` if all your your max values are 127 or lower.)

Comment: The decrementing can be done by keeping the counters decremented by one and then doing vpminub with your reset value.  This resets the counters when they roll over to 0xff. In parallel, you can do a comparison to find if that happened.

Comment: @fuz: Nice, I thought there should be something involving `pminub` and/or better critical-path latency but wasn't seeing it right away; that's one reason I didn't post an answer.

Comment: If I'm decrementing I'd reload the byte with the maximum when it reaches 0. By the way I'm new to using XMM/YMM for actual math. Currently I'm doing these increments (or decrements) in the main registers, which I assume is less efficient due to all the branching. A related question, is there a good primer on AVX?

Comment: You said that in the question, with about the same phrasing.  That doesn't help me be sure that you want the loop body to only see numbers from 150 down to 1, never a `0`.  What I was asking is whether the "inner loop" for each element is like `do{}while(--i)` (`sub`/`jnz` so the loop body never runs with i=0) or `do{}while(i--)` (`sub`/`jnc` so it runs with zero but not after the subtraction produces a borrow).

Comment: There's some info in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info , like Agner Fog's optimization guide.  AVX1 / AVX2 are mostly just wider versions of SSE stuff, and a couple new operations.  Not a new way of thinking about anything, so reading good stuff about SSE techniques is still useful.

Comment: Which instruction set extensions can you use specifically?  Just AVX?   Or also AVX2?  What about AVX-512?  If yes, which extensions?

Comment: My current machine is a Ryzen 7840U but AMD's page about it avoids mentioning which standards it supports. Another page I found says it even does AVX512. But my hardware situation will likely change soon. I also have an aarch64 which has NEON. I'll probably try the same SIMD optimization on that.

Comment: You have a Zen 4, so you have AVX2+FMA3, and a bunch of AVX-512 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512).  A reasonable baseline feature set for most modern CPUs is [x86-64-v3 (Haswell) and Excavator/Zen1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels), although until very recently "Pentium" and "Celeron" branded CPUs didn't have AVX, and low-power Intel Silvermont-family didn't have AVX2+FMA3 until the latest generation.

Comment: AVX-512 support is mixed, with Intel Alder Lake and later dropping it, even with P-core-only configs :( :(  It'll be back in a 256-bit-only form as AVX10.2 on their later hybrid CPUs.  Which future Zen CPUs will still support, along with full-width AVX-512.  See https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_4 for more about it, and https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_3 for a complete ISA feature list for the previous generation.

Comment: Great thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing the counters decremented by one.  I.e. they start at *limit − 1* and you want to be informed when they roll over from 0 to −1, not from 1 to 0.  Then you can solve this as follows:

```
# ymm0 holds the counters
# ymm1 holds the limits
# ymm2 holds 1 in each byte (or 0xff in each byte and use vpsubb)
# ymm3 holds 0 in each byte
vpcmpeqb  %ymm0, %ymm3, %ymm4    # which of the counters is zero?
vptest    %ymm4, %ymm4           # clear ZF if any counter was zero
vpsubb    %ymm2, %ymm0, %ymm0    # decrement counters
vpminub   %ymm1, %ymm0, %ymm0    # reset rolled-over counters to limits
jnz       .Lrollover             # do something if a counter rolled over
```

This code is meant to illustrate the general idea.  For some tips on making it faster, see Peter Cordes' great comments below.

Comment: For beginners, note that creating a vector of `-1` (0xFF) bytes is cheaper than a vector of `1` bytes.  Just `vpmpeqb %ymm2, %ymm2, %ymm2`.  That's why you'd want to add or subtract `-1` instead of sub or add `+1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had briefly considered mentioning that, but wanted to not distract with this detail.  Please also see my [chat request](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149001/room-for-fuz-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: Also, `vptest` costs 2 uops on current CPUs.  (1 uop on AMD Zen 2 and earlier, and Intel E cores; well 1 uop per 128-bit lane on E cores).  And it can't macro-fuse with JNZ even if you put them together, so if you're going to branch it's actually cheaper to do `vpmovmskb %ymm4, %eax` (1 uop) / `test %eax, %eax; jnz` (1 fused uop on both Intel and AMD), despite the extra machine-code bytes.  Also, if branch latency isn't important, you can compare after the `min` to find out which elements rolled over, saving a (very cheap) `vpxor` zeroing insn and a YMM register.

Comment: Using `vpmovmskb` also makes it possible to do something like `add $-1, %eax` to set CF if any of the mask bits were non-zero in EAX, if for example you want to branchlessly count roll-overs with `adc $0, %ecx` or something.  But if you just want to branch and then find the rollover element, use `test` and check ZF so you can still bit-scan the mask with `lzcnt` or `tzcnt` to find the first or last rollover.  (And `blsi` / `jnz` to keep looping while there are more mask bits if you want to find all the rollovers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm finding that VPTEST ymm4,ymm4 doesn't set Z to 1 if *any* of the values is 0. It sets it to zero if *all* of the values are 0. Also if I do "VPTEST ymm4,ymm0" where ymm0 has all zeros, Z is always set.

Comment: @thequestioner: That's correct, it's like the scalar `test` instruction. (as documented: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest).  `x & 0` is always 0, so ZF will always be set.  IDK why you're replying to me; I hope I didn't imply anything incorrect about how `ptest` works in comments here.  [Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43712243) might be helpful in wrapping your head around what can be done with `ptest`.

Comment: @PeterCordes If I need to know whether 1 or more bytes in a vector have been decremented to zero, do I need to perform n tests, one per byte in the vector?

Comment: I wonder if instead I need to use VPCMPUB and then somehow read out the mask register. Can I check whether the mask is all 0's?

Comment: @thequestioner: Yeah, but you don't need AVX-512 unsigned compares when testing for equality.  Just `vpcmpeqb` / `vpmovmskb`.  Like [Check for zeros horizontally across \_\_m128i vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23206418), or [Check all bytes of a \_\_m128i for a match of a single byte using SSE/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897297) with a constant `_mm_setzero_si128()`.

Comment: @thequestioner: Or stuff like an integer equivalent of [Intel SIMD - How can I check if an \_\_m256\* contains any non-zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28923766) or [Test if any byte in an xmm register is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62357845).  There are many of these Q&As; surprised you didn't find them.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see now why you guys were saying I should look for an underflow instead of reaching 0. That's where the mask becomes useful because it uses the high bit of the byte. However I really wanted to use all 8 bits for the counters e.g. some starting values would be >= 128. In fact, I might want to use 16-bit counters later. I don't see that there is a vpmovmskw.

Comment: @thequestioner: Are you talking about the same problem fuz's answer is answering?  (Is this your question from a different account?)  It does work for full-range, using `vpminub` to select `200` in counters that have rolled over to `0xff`.  And it actually compares each element against `0`, it's not using movemask or ptest on the original counter.  You can use `vpmovmskb` on any `vpcmp` result, regardless of element width, e.g. `vpcmpeqw` + `vpmovmskb` will give you 2 bits per SIMD element, which is fine if you only care about whether any matched.  If you tzcnt, scale by 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes In my current code I'm using words instead of bytes. I've got these word counters working and I can move the mask into a main register. However I've encountered a problem. In order to reset a counter that became -1 back to its original value, it appears I need to use VPBLENDM, but this is an AVX512 instruction. What did people use before AVX512 for this purpose?

Comment: `vpsubw` / `vpminuw` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pminub:pminuw) should work identically to how fuz's answer is using `vpsubb` / `vpminub`.  With SSE4.1 and later, integer `min` is available in an unsigned form for all 4 element sizes.  For the general case if you did need a blend, word compare and `vpblendvb` still works: compare results have the high bit set or clear in every byte of element.